I wrote a O(log N) code for largest element in an array today but is this an already existing way to find max element in an array?
Largest element in an array's most optimal approach. The code I have written has passed all test cases in https://www.naukri.com/code360/problems/largest-element-in-the-array-largest-element-in-the-array_5026279, and it computes in O(logN) time.   Are there any mistakes here?  And I cannot find any solutions that exists in LogN time computation. Is there any edge cases to this?
static int largestElement(int[] arr, int n) {
    // Write your code here.
    int max = arr[0];
    int i = 1;
    int j = n-1;
    while(i<=j){
        if(arr[i]>=max  && arr[i] >= arr[j]) max = arr[i];
        else if(arr[j]>=max  && arr[j] >= arr[i]) max = arr[j];
        i++;
        j--;
    }
    return max;
}


Java? C#? Something else?

This isn't O(log(n)). It is O(n).

linear algorithm
The OP code does not complete in \$O(\log n)\$ logarithmic time.
In general a correct algorithm will have at least \$O(n)\$ linear complexity.
It cannot do better than that,
since the maximum element could be hiding at any position.
code
This line of source code is correct:
    int max = arr[0];

In particular, initializing in this way is better
than using a \$- \infty\$ sentinel such as \$-(2^{63})\$.
The remainder of the code should be rewritten, as a short loop.
(When initially reading it, I was kind of hoping that assignment
would immediately produce the answer in \$O(1)\$ constant time
by virtue of input being in monotonic decreasing sorted order,
but then I saw the problem puts no constraint on the input vector.)
Please delete that "Write your code here" comment line.
Just write a linear scan of the input integers, and you're done.
No need to approach it from both ends -- ascending indexes will suffice.
braces
        if(arr[i]>=max  && arr[i] >= arr[j]) max = arr[i];

Please don't do that.
Surround if / else statements with { } braces,
even if there's only a single statement as we see here.
The way the OP code is phrased,
it invites maintenance headaches down the road.
We don't want some hapless engineer to add a second statement
and mispredict how the compiled code will behave.
